# Does "Pictura Mentum" mean anything?

Tags: etymology, latin

I know that the etymology of the word "pigment" is the Latin verb *pingere* (to paint) plus the suffix *-mentum* (instrument used in the accomplishment of the action).

I know that the *-mentum* suffix is used with verbs and adjectives, but not with nouns.

I have a project which I want to call "pictura mentum", but I don't know if that  means anything or if at least it is well-formed Latin.

Comment: No, this is not well-formed Latin. See how the word "mens" is usually declined in Latin http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mens

Comment: Thanks Alex. Could "pictura mentum" mean something like "instrument for making pictures"?

Comment: The _-mentum_ suffix (probably) has nothing to do with the word _mens_, but is a collocation of two IE nominalising suffixes _-mn̩_ and _-tom_. It is added to a root, not to an inflected form such as _pictura_.

Comment: Thanks Colin. I think I would use "pictare mentum" which I've seen is kind of a vulgar form of "pingere mentum". Am I right?

Comment: You can use anything you like. But if _pictare mentum_ is Latin it means something like "to keep painting a chin" (assuming that _pictare_ is a frequentative of _pingere_). _Mentum_ as an independent word means "chin".

Comment: Apparently, there is also the verb _picturare_ so it could in fact be one word _picturamentum_, i.e. a picture.

Answer (score -2):

It means "Picture of the Mind." Pictura is in the nominative case while Mentum is a genitive which we think of as meaning "of the mind."

Comment: Thanks Ian. I was thinking it could mean something like "instrument for making pictures" but I was wrong. Anyway, I like this other meaning. Do you think pictura mentum "picture of the mind" could be interpreted as "thought" or  "thinking" ("pensamiento" in spanish)?. Or what could be the interpretation of such words?

Comment: Umm .. not exactly. Genitive singular of *mens* is ***mentis***. Genitive plural is ***mentium***.

Comment: Thanks StoneyB. So in order to mean "picture of the mind" it must be something like "pictura mentis"? Could "pictura mentum" mean anything?

Comment: _[Mentum](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=mentum&la=la&can=mentum1&prior=mentum#lexicon)_, -ī, n also means 'chin; beard'. Since it's neuter 2nd declension, NomSg, VocSg and AcSg are all _mentum_; and there's a "poetic" GenPl _mentum_ as well. So it could be 'a picture of beards'. If that means anything.